# Explicit interface derivation: private method accessible as public one

Tags: c#

I have a problem with understanding some C# code:)

I have a 2 interfaces IClassB and IClass, each of them with one method, no matter the name & signature. Im doing class ClassC which implements them both: IClassB explicitly and IClassA implicitly. So I have code:

```
 public class ClassC: IClassA, IClassB
        {
        void IClassB.methodForClassB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method for explicit implementation");
        }

        public void methodForClassA()
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("method for implicit implementation");
        }
    }
```

As you see: method void IClassB.methodForClassB() is private (isn't it?).
But when I use this ClassC object, I can call method methodForClassB as it would be a public method. How to explain it?

```
ClassC classC = new ClassC();

IClassB classB = new ClassC();
classB.methodForClassB();*

((IClassB)classC).methodForClassB();
```

Comment: The whole point of an interface is to be able to call its methods (see also the Liskov Substitution Principle).  You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to [The C# Language Specification, 13.4.1 Explicit interface member implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> It is a compile-time error for an explicit interface member implementation to include access modifiers, and it is a compile-time error to include the modifiers abstract, virtual, override, or static.

Such methods have to be accessed via a reference to the interface and they have the same access level as the interface itself (either `public` or `internal`).